# Конвертация аудио файла при загрузке на сервер

Tags: javascript, аудио, mp3, конвертация, ogg

Подскажите, есть ли плагины или библиотеки для конвертации аудио файла из mp3 в ogg в момент загрузки на сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript для таких задач не предназначен (как и php), но с помощью php вы можете написать обработчик для библиотек, которые занимаются конвертацией файлов.

В этом вам поможет exec() - https://www.php.net/function.exec

### Вариант раз: FFMPEG

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Библиотека для php: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

### Вариант два: SoX

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

в SoX вы работаете с файлами через командную строку сервера.

Примеры: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/sound-exchange-sox-15-examples-to-manipulate-audio-files/

Итого - в момент загрузки файла на сервер, вам нужно сервером вызывать запуск одного из этих решений, конвертировать как вам надо, получать ответ и дальше обрабатывать свой запрос с новым файлом.

Надеюсь помог.